# The @article parameter value must be 'all' for immediate_sync publications

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a publication of 4 tables and many subscribers (transactional push replication), most of them being interested by one of those 4 tables.

Everything is working fine as long as I create the subscription for all articles:

```
EXEC sp_addsubscription 
    @publication = @publicationName,
    @subscriber = @subscriber,
    @destination_db = @DatabaseName,
    @subscription_type = N'push',
    @article = 'all';
```

But I get an error if I change

```
@article = 'TableName'
```

**The @article parameter value must be 'all' for immediate_sync publications.**

Why this happens? How can I create a subscription only for one of those 4 tables (=4 articles)?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can't subscribe to one article in a publication, you must subscribe to all articles in the publication. You could add each article as it's own publication however, and then subscribe to whichever ones you need.

Comment: It's very strange the behaviour, but thanks for the answer... Anyway, how do you explain @article parameter of sp_addsubscription?

Comment: I believe it is used after you add an article to a publication, this will update the subscription to include the new article prior to re-initializing and generating a new snapshot.